# Live chat room event: Delta IV Heavy to Launch NROL-65 (August 28, 2013 at 5:30 p.m. UTC/GMT)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, announcement, scheduled-event

This is an invitation to attend [our chat room event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9682/the-pod-bay?tab=schedule), where we will be covering the launch of the [ULA](http://www.ulalaunch.com/site/default.shtml) (United Launch Alliance) [Delta IV-Heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_IV_Heavy) configuration delivering the classified NROL-65 payload to orbit for the [United States National Reconnaissance Office](http://www.nro.gov/) (NRO).

Chat event will start 20 minutes before the first launch window time.

[image]

---

**Live Broadcast**

> **[Delta IV Heavy to Launch NROL-65](http://www.ulalaunch.com/site/pages/Multimedia_Webcast.shtml)**
>
> **Rocket/Payload**: A Delta IV Heavy configuration will launch the
>   NROL-65 mission for the National Reconnaissance Office (NRO).
>
> **Date/Site/Launch Time**: Wednesday, Aug. 28, from Space Launch Complex
>   (SLC) 6 at Vandenberg Air Force Base, Calif.
>
> **Viewing the Launch by Webcast**: The launch will be webcast live; the
>   time will be posted closer to the launch date.
>
> **Launch Notes**: NROL-65 will be ULA’s eighth launch in 2013 and the
>   company’s 74th overall. The mission will be the 24th Delta IV flight
>   since the vehicle’s inaugural launch in 2002 and the second time the
>   Delta IV Heavy has launched from the West Coast.
>
> **Mission Description**: The mission will be launched for the National
>   Reconnaissance Office in support of national defense.
>
> **Launch Updates**: To keep up to speed with updates to the launch
>   countdown, dial the ULA launch hotline at 1-877-852-4321. Join the
>   conversation at [facebook.com/ulalaunch](https://www.facebook.com/ulalaunch) and [twitter.com/ulalaunch](https://twitter.com/ulalaunch); look
>   for the #NROL65 hashtag.

---

**Your local times for the start of the chat room event**

```
Timezone      Date        Local time
------------------------------------
GMT/UTC       August 28    5:30 p.m.
CET/CEST      August 28    7:30 p.m.
EST/EDT       August 28    1:30 p.m.
PST/PDT       August 28   10:30 a.m.
```

[image: World Time]

If you can't find your timezone in the list above, you can use the [World Time Buddy](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/) tool.

---

**Welcome to our chat room - [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay) - where we will discuss this event and post links to live streams covering the launch!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## MISSION SUCCESS!
>
> ### America's largest rocket lifts off from California
>
> Igniting its three main engines in a staggered sequence for the first
> time, a United Launch Alliance Delta 4-Heavy rocket successfully flew
> into Earth orbit and deployed a U.S. national security satellite on
> August 28, 2013.
>
> [image: Delta IV Heavy launching NROL-65 (August 28, 2013)]
>
> The United Launch Alliance Delta 4-Heavy rocket has successfully
> launched its classified payload for the U.S. National Reconnaissance
> Office following liftoff at 11:03 a.m. local time today from Space
> Launch Complex 6 at Vandenberg Air Force Base, Calif.
>
> *"We are truly honored to deliver this critical asset to orbit,"* said
> Jim Sponnick, ULA vice president, Atlas and Delta Programs. *"The ULA
> Delta 4-Heavy is currently the world’s largest rocket, providing the
> nation with reliable, proven, heavy lift capability for our country's
> national security payloads from both the east and west coasts. I
> congratulate the combined NRO, Air Force, ULA, and supplier team on
> today's successful launch of the NROL-65 mission."*
>
> ► **[Video of the Delta IV Heavy launching NROL-65](http://twitpic.com/dasaxj)**